# startActivityForResult workflow

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, start-activity

I'm using an Activity A which starts another Activity B to get a result (the id of a customer), all seems to work perfectly but I have few error reports which tend to indicate that I have a concurrency bug between the UI building process and the onActivityResult method.

The whole hypothesis is based on the fact that the Activity A could have been destroyed during the appearance of the Activity B and created again which can create problems because Activity A creates its UI by doing some asynchronous network requests.

Of course, I'm not able to reproduce the bug (stopping the activity manually would be the nearest reproduction but only if the problem is the concurrence bug I mentioned).

So, in short,

> Is it possible that an activity starting another one for result is cut by the OS while the user is in the newly created activity? (and then recreated when the user is finished and when `setResult` and `finish` are called on the newly created activity).

**-- Update --**

Sorry for the imprecision, Activity A is containing a `Fragment` which is starting the `Activity` and doing the network stuff, so it's maybe a matter of fragment (so the question is also "could the OS cut a Fragment which started an activity for result?").

Comment: in short: yes it is possible ... *Of course, I'm not able to reproduce the bug* ... well there is a debugging option which will force such behaviour ... "Don't Keep Activities" or something

Comment: Really? I'll be very interested to know this option because I know the debugger pretty well :D

Comment: here is an image: http://android-er.blogspot.com/2013/04/simulate-kill-activity-to-test.html

Comment: Ah you meant a developer option. Thanks, didn't tested this one. :D

Comment: not clear, need Error Log.

Comment: If activity was killed the fragments from activity will be killed, too(and recreated)...  So it is the same problem...

Comment: So it's basically possible that the OS kill an activity waiting for a result... Fine! I didn't calculate that, thanks guys ! :D